# A non well formed numeric value encountered using implode()

Tags: php, implode

```
$revenue = $price - ( (float) $cost_price + implode(' + ', $computed['overheads']) );
```

.. results in a notice:

```
Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in ...
```

Wonder whats causing it and how can I fix it?

Comment: it is obvious that `$computer['overheads']` might contain non-numeric characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `implode` with the `+` sign, it creates a string out of an array and adds `+` between each item in the array, that is, it will not evaluate the code into a equation.

If you know that all the values in the array is of the float (or some numeric type) you could use the `array_sum` function, which creates a sum of all the values in the array.

Something like:

```
$revenue = $price - ((float)$cost_price + array_sum($computed['overheads']));
```

Comment: Happy to help, feel free to mark answer as correct :)